# What is the Fourier transform of fermion coherent state to evaluate the path integral for hopping Hamiltonian?

Tags: condensed-matter, fourier-transform, path-integral, fermions

while doing the path integral quatization of fermions with hopping hamiltonian (from Atland Simmons equation 4.26 P.No.167 and P.No.169 eqn.No.4.33), the hamiltonian is diagonalized using a unitary transformation. We already know that this hamiltonian with nearest neighbor interaction can be diagonalised by taking Fourier transform of the annihilation and creation operators. However, how does state function which is grassmanian number as a function of frequency of imaginary time be transformed under Fourier transform. Is there anything like Fourier transform for the coherent states? Please help me proceed further and also suggest some other material to understand this better

Comment: Define the *annihilation operator* destroying a particle in the Fock space of occupation number and associating to this particle a wave-function in the Hilbert space parametrised by the momentum $k$ as the product of a (wave-)function $\Psi$ in the Hilbert space only and an operator $\hat{A}$ acting in the Fock space only as  $\hat{a}\left(k\right)=\Psi\left(k\right)\hat{A}$. Then the Fourier transform of \hat{a} would be the Fourier transform of the function $\Psi$ (now in the dual space) times the same operator $\hat{A}$ acting in Fock's space. $\hat{a}$ is called a particle-field operator.

Comment: As the author states, "due to the boundary conditions, the functions $\psi(\tau)$ can be interpreted as functions on the entire time axis which are periodic/antiperiodic on the interval $[0,\beta]$. As such they can be represented in terms of a Fourier series [...]". 
I do not find this book's presentation very clear. I usually refer to Negele and Orland's Quantum Many-particle Systems,  ISBN-13: 978-0738200521